# PyQT: how to dump all items into a file?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Okay there is a QListView with a standard model.

How to iterate over ALL the items in the list (or get them all at once), and transform their content into Python's list of strings?

There are tons of receipts for PyQT4, and hours of googling gave me nothing for PyQT5. That's just terrible! I'm really upset we chose version 5, but that wasn't my choice =(

```
(somewhere in the UI)
self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)


(somewhere in the View code)
def users_to_list_view(users, list_view):
    list_model = QStandardItemModel(list_view)
    for user in users:
        item = QStandardItem(user.username)
        list_model.appendRow(item)
    list_view.setModel(list_model)

def someSignal():
    ...
    users_to_list_view(users, self.ui.listView)    

def onSave():
    ...

    AND HERE I WANT TO GET ALL THE ITEMS FROM THAT BLOODY LIST!
```

Comment: Could you give us some code that you have running?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

```
def users_to_list_view(users, list_view):
    self.list_model = QStandardItemModel(list_view)
    for user in users:
        item = QStandardItem(user.username)
        self.list_model.appendRow(item)
    list_view.setModel(list_model)


def onSave():
    self.list_model. # get items with some method
```